# no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

Tags: c++, oop

I am quite new to object oriented programming. I'm trying to modularize a code in a class format in order to make things easy to understand and make the code extendable.

I am stuck with this error:

```
   Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [src/interface.o] Error 1 Emulation-SW    /virtualization_proj        C/C++ Problem
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....   Emulation-SW    /virtualization_proj        C/C++ Problem
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’  interface.h /virtualization_proj/src    line 58 C/C++ Problem
recipe for target 'src/interface.o' failed  makefile    /virtualization_proj/Emulation-SW   line 57 C/C++ Problem
```

The error looks in the IDE as below:

[image]

Can someone help in resolving this error?

```
class INTERFACE{
   
    public:
    
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    cl::Device device;
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Context context;
    cl::CommandQueue q;

    cl::Program::Binaries bins;
    char *buf;
    unsigned nb;
    
    cl::Program program;

    int push_xclbinFile_to_FPGA(){
      bins.push_back({buf,nb});  // Push_back function is not getting recognized
      devices.resize(1);
      program= cl::Program(context, devices, bins);
      return 1;

    }
 
};
```

**Edit**

To make the question more clear, these lines work completely fine when I execute them from the `main()` function as below. I hope this will clarify the question a little more.

[image]

**Edit**

The `main` file code is as below:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    // Compute the size of array in bytes
     INTERFACE i_obj;
     size_t size_in_bytes= i_obj.compute_size_in_bytes();

    // Finding the device
     int device_found= i_obj.finding_platform();
     if(device_found==0){
         std::cout<< "Device found successfully" << std::endl;
     }

    // Creating Context and Command Queue for selected device
    cl::Context context(i_obj.devices);
    cl::CommandQueue q(context, i_obj.device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);
    i_obj.context= context;
    i_obj.q= q;



     VMGR *vm=new VMGR();
     vm->initialize_mq();             // Creating the Queue1


    while(1){


    std::vector<std::string> numbers = vm->run();

    int st=i_obj.buffer_values();


        //setting input data

        if (numbers.size()!=0){



            if(numbers[2]=="SUB"){
//
                    // Read the xclbin file
                  int status_xclbin_read= i_obj.reading_the_xclbinFile(vm);

                 //  Process the read Data

                  i_obj.bins.push_back({i_obj.buf,i_obj.nb});

                  (i_obj.devices).resize(1);



                  // Push the xclbin file into the FPGA
              cl::Program program(i_obj.context, i_obj.devices, i_obj.bins);


                 // This call will get the kernel object from program. A kernel is an
                    // OpenCL function that is executed on the FPGA.
                  i_obj.krnl_vector_sub= cl::Kernel(program,"krnl_vsub");


                int narg=0;

                 // set the kernel Arguments
                i_obj.krnl_vector_sub.setArg(narg++,i_obj.buffer_a);
                i_obj.krnl_vector_sub.setArg(narg++,i_obj.buffer_b);

                i_obj.krnl_vector_sub.setArg(narg++,i_obj.buffer_result);

                i_obj.krnl_vector_sub.setArg(narg++,api::DATA_SIZE);
                //We then need to map our OpenCL buffers to get the pointers
                i_obj.ptr_a = (int *) (i_obj.q).enqueueMapBuffer (i_obj.buffer_a , CL_TRUE , CL_MAP_WRITE , 0, size_in_bytes);
                i_obj.ptr_b = (int *) (i_obj.q).enqueueMapBuffer (i_obj.buffer_b , CL_TRUE , CL_MAP_WRITE , 0, size_in_bytes);

                i_obj.ptr_result = (int *) (i_obj.q).enqueueMapBuffer (i_obj.buffer_result , CL_TRUE , CL_MAP_READ , 0, size_in_bytes);

                i_obj.bins.clear();




            }

        (i_obj.q).finish();




           


    }

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: What is `buf`? Kindly provide a MVCE (minimum, verifiable, complete example).

Comment: @looro I apologize. I edited the question just now.

Comment: A guess: you're probably looking for {buf,buf+nb} i.e. start and end pointers. Vector doesn't have a constructor that takes a start pointer and length

Comment: `char *buf;` -- If your goal is to make things maintainable, using pointers will go against that plan.  Why not `std::string buf;`, or even `std::vector<char> buf`;?

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie for the response. I have edited the question to make it little more clear. This three lines are like pushing the bin file in accelerator. Since, I have add some handshaking in this work, I need to make these functionalities on pushing bin file , adding etc in form of separate functions so that they can be easily called whenever required.

Comment: Thank you @user253751. I have edited the question to make it little more clear.

Comment: @Deepika You should post as text, not images.  If anyone now wants to test the code that you say works, they cannot easily copy and paste it.  Anyway, isn't it easier to simply copy and paste, rather than creating images?  I don't get why so many want to post images, when it is less work to simply copy and paste text.

Comment: Are you sure it works in `main`? Maybe the compiler is not getting to that part of the code because of the earlier error, so it doesn't see the error? (This is a real thing that happens with C and C++ compilers. And because the language is so complex the IDE's "simple error checker" doesn't see the error either)

Comment: Thank you @user253751. I have edited the question and pasted all the error I am getting.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie. I have included the main function. Please review.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik for the response. I working on editing the question properly.

Comment: This is still not an [mcve].  What is `cl::Device`?  What is `cl::Context`?  Imagine if we have a blank CPP file, and we are to copy *exactly* what you are posting, and paste it into the blank CPP file.  What results do you think we will get?  [Here is what I get when I copy/paste your exact code into godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e7d7bz738).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bins.push_back({buf,nb})` makes no sense.  Because of that the compiler can't figure out what type `{buf,nb}` is supposed to be.

Based on your error message, `bins` is a `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>`, which means `bins.push_back` needs you to pass it a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  `{buf,nb}` can't be converted to a `std::vector<unsigned char>` though, since neither `buf`, nor `nb` are `unsigned char`s (one is a `char*` and the other an `unsigned int`).

Note that the [documentation](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html#af804a4cb0e2dc844c0be0b0b76dbd25a) for the relevant `cl::Program` constructor appears to be incorrect.  It is documented to accept a vector of `(bin, size)` pairs, but it does not.  It just accepts a vector of vectors containing binary data.  `std::vector` knows its own size, so that doesn't need to be passed separately.  Looking at [the code](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/blob/main/include/CL/opencl.hpp#L6556) it appears that documentation was once correct, but the interface has changed based on the preprocessor conditionals in that constructor.

Comment: Thank you @Miles Budnek for the response. Below is the link of the code of vector addition. Here buf is char pointer and nb is unsigned type.
 
 
 https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis_Accel_Examples/blob/master/cpp_kernels/simple_vadd/src/vadd.cpp

Comment: @Deepika Like I said, the interface changed at some point.  You're likely to find a number of examples of the old interface where `cl::Program::Binaries` was a typedef for `std::vector<std::pair<const void*, size_t>>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>`.  You can get the old interface back by defining the preprocessor token `CL_HPP_ENABLE_PROGRAM_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_ARRAY_COMPATIBILITY`.

Comment: Thank you @Miles Budnek for your kind help.